# What is the right place for the word "probably" in a future perfect sentence?

Tags: word-order, future-tense, adverb-placement

For example: "By the time these clothes fit me, they..."

> 1. will probably have been out of fashion
> 2. probably will have been out of fashion

Comment: There would usually be a time-phrase in such statements, such as "for a year or two"  and  immediately before such a phrase is another place where **probably** can appear.  *Those hats will have been out of fashion probably for a year or two when you finally decide to buy one.*

Comment: I think you mean clothes, not cloths, which generally means separate pieces of material, not garments.

Comment: "will *be* out of fashion" sounds better to me unless you add "out of fashion for ..." to qualify that. I think you're ok with either choice in your original question though.

Answer (score 2):

The "probably" can go in either position.

By the time these **clothes** fit me, they..."

1a. will probably **be** out of fashion.
1b. probably will **be** out of fashion

2a. will probably **have been** out of fashion for **x amount** of time.
2b. probably will **have been** out of fashion for **x amount** of time.

As you can see, "the probably" can be in either postition.

Comment: Well, I see that the original question has been edited somewhat, so my answers to number 1.  with the 'be' in it does not make as much sense as it did...

Comment: Is there some difference between `a` ("will probably") and `b` ("probably will")? At least tiny one?